# nginx https to http

Tags: php, nginx, https

Суть вот в чем - на сайте при определенном условии урл должен измениться с https на http.

```
if (strpos($url, 'http://') !== false) {
    if ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "on") {
        $url = "http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        header("Location: $url");
        exit;
   }
}
```

Но редирект почему-то не работает. Когда я пыталась вручную в браузере изменить урл (https на http поменять) - меня перекидывало назад на http

Может быть проблема в nginx? Есть какое-то правило, которое не позволяет редирект на http?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно смотреть конфиг nginx. Без него мы не скажем есть ли там такое правило.

Некоторые хостеры позволяют настроить для домена редирект с http на https, в этом случае редирект произойдет ещё до вашего nginx.

Непосредственно в nginx решение вашей проблемы будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name blah-blah-blah;

    # ...

    location /ololo { # Нужный вам урл
        if ($scheme = 'https') {
            rewrite ^/(.*) http://$server_name/$1 permanent;
        }
    }

    # ...
}
```

> **НО!**
>
> Я встречал конфигурации, когда в одной директиве `server` настроены и `http`, и `https` (Чаще всего в них просто происходит редирект с http на https). В таком случае можно словить бесконечное перенаправление страницы. Нужно будет эту логику обработать.